# Does jsonschema2pojo support xml format, if it does, possible what's the way?

Tags: java, json

`jsonschema2pojo` is not supporting `xml` format. Please let me know does `jsonschema2pojo` support `xml` and what is the solution for this?

Comment: Can you add more details?

Comment: No, it supports JSON format only, For XML format, you can use [Convert XML Schema to Java Pojo Classes - Online](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/pojoFromXSD.html) instead.